# r - subset multiple data frames (or one list) based on cut-offs from a reference data frame

Tags: r

I have a series of data frames representing separate molecules (`F0001, F0002,...,`) that contain hundeds/thousands of scores from experiments using that molecule. Each data frame looks like this.

**F0001**

```
    PoseID  Score
1   AAAA_1  -13.70
2   AAAA_2  -9.21
3   AAAA_3  -7.60
4   AAAA_4  -6.28
5   ....
```

**F0002**

```
    PoseID  Score
1   AAAB_1  -14.90
2   AAAB_2  -13.92
3   AAAB_3  -13.49
4   AAAB_4  -11.95
5   ....
```

etc., etc.

Based on a cut-off, I'd like to sub-set the data to throw out any of the poses that fall above said cut-off, so, a simple binary comparison. A slight complicating factor is that the cut-off differs for each of (`F0001, F0002,...,`) so I've gone ahead and stored those in a data frame (let's call it `cutoffs`.

**cutoffs**

```
     FragmentID     ScoreCutOff
1    F0001          -9.69
2    F0002          -9.33
3    F0003          -8.50
4    ....
```

So I guess the question becomes, do I perform the comparison between `cutoffs` and each data frame or add all the data frames to a list and perform the comparison between `cutoffs` and the list of data frames there?

I'm feeling that [Ari Friedman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16267826/4994561) is in the ballpark so I'm tooling about with sapply/any to get it working, usually one solves this sort of problem quite easily with nested loops and data structures in Python/CPP/Java but I'm new to doing it in R so I'm keen to hear of any other ideas people have. Of course, if I solve it myself in the interim, will post solution for critique.

Comment: I'd first build a list of named dataframes from the cutoffs$FragmentID column and then use `mapply` on that list as the first argument and second argument as the corresponding $ScoreCutoff value. Looks like too much work to set it up. You should learn to post examples written in R.

Comment: Yeah cheers, I'm new to the site so didn't think to do that.

Comment: Above comment is @ person who reminded me to tick the correct solution but whose comment is no longer there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming df1, df2 as you dataframes, you could try this using `lapply`

```
dflist = list(df1, df2)
names(dflist) = cutoffs$FragmentID

out = lapply(names(dflist), 
      function(x){ 
        cfval = subset(cutoff, FragmentID %in% x); 
        subset(dflist[[x]], Score < cfval$ScoreCutOff)
      })

names(out) = cutoff$FragmentID

#> out
#$F0001
#  PoseID Score
#1 AAAA_1 -13.7
# 
#$F0002
#  PoseID  Score
#1 AAAB_1 -14.90
#2 AAAB_2 -13.92
#3 AAAB_3 -13.49
#4 AAAB_4 -11.95
```

later if you want to have all the data-frames seperately, you could do this

```
# data-frames with names F0001, F0002, ....
list2env(out,.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Pretty much perfect. Nothing wrong with the other solution but I'm digging on s/l/m/apply these days. Cheers again!

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the information you provide, something like that should do the job:

```
# bring your data.frames into a list:
f <- list( F0001, F0002 )
> f
[[1]]
  PoseID  Score
1 AAAA_1 -13.70
2 AAAA_2  -9.21
3 AAAA_3  -7.60
4 AAAA_4  -6.28

[[2]]
  PoseID  Score
1 AAAB_1 -14.90
2 AAAB_2 -13.92
3 AAAB_3 -13.49
4 AAAB_4 -11.95

# subset per list item
for( i in 1 : length( f ) ) 
    f[[ i ]] <- f[[ i ]][ f[[ i ]][ 2 ] < cutoffs[ i, 2 ], ]
> f
[[1]]
  PoseID Score
1 AAAA_1 -13.7

[[2]]
  PoseID  Score
1 AAAB_1 -14.90
2 AAAB_2 -13.92
3 AAAB_3 -13.49
4 AAAB_4 -11.95
```

Not sure what you mean with "above cut-off", maybe you have to reverse the less-than `<` operation. I also assume that in `cutoffs`, the data have exactly the same order as in the list of data.frames, otherwise some additional operation to identify the corresponding cut-off may be necessary.

Comment: Yeah sorry, should have been clearer. Basically, these are energy scores so lower = better but I was using 'above' in terms of magnitude.

Comment: Your solution a good one too, FYI, but I'm giving the vote to the apply method in this case, mainly for consistency as that's how I've been doing it of late. I'm new so can't just upvote yet....