# Subsetting data frame based on columns

Tags: r, subset

I would like to remove certain rows from data based on values in one column. I have tried a few approaches:

```
#reads in data
sbc016formants.df <- read.table("file path", sep="\t", header = F, strip.white = T)

# names columns
names(sbc016formants.df) <- c("fileName", "start", "end", "vowelLabel")

# list of values I want to remove
list16 <- c(615.162, 775.885)

# produces a subset of data - removes rows with values from list 16 in the start column
sbc016formants.df <- subset(sbc016formants.df, !start %in% list16)
```

which produces this error message for some, but not all of my data files:

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
'match' requires vector arguments
```

I also tried this, based on the second answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267750/subsetting-data-frame-based-on-contents-of-a-column-list) topic

```
sbc002formants.df <- sbc002formants.df[ apply(sbc002formants.df, 1 , function(x) any(unlist(x) %in% list2) ) , ]
```

And this gets rid of some of the items on the list (`list16`), but not all. I wanted to use the first answer, but I don't understand the code (I'm not sure what `bl` is, in the example).

Here is the code to make a reproducible example:

```
# creates dataframe
fileName <- c("sbc016", "sbc016", "sbc016", "sbc016")
start <- c(1.345, 2.345, 615.162, 775.885)
end <- c(100.345, 200.345, 715.162, 875.885)
sbc016formants.df <- data.frame(fileName, start, end)

# list of what I want to get rid of
list16 <- c(615.162, 775.885)
```

Comment: try `sbc016formants.df[!(sbc016formants.df$start %in% list16),]`?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error but I do not get an error message

Comment: @aichao, this doesn't produce any error message, but it does not do the subsetting, either.

Comment: @aichaos comment **does** sub-setting and it **works** on your example data

Comment: Hmm, it does for me on your reproducible example. Also, I agree with @Pieter that your `subset` command, which is equivalent, does not produce an error on your reproducible example. So, we are forced to conclude that there is something with your data that is not the same as your reproducible example.

Comment: Are you sure the column you are using is numeric and not numbers but as characters or so?

Comment: I used `as.numeric` on the column in the data frame, double checking it with `is.numeric`, and I used `is.numeric` to check the list, and they both came back as `TRUE`. I can't quite figure out what is wrong with my data.

Comment: I used `length(intersect(list16, sbc016formants.df$start))` which returns `10`, so it doesn't make sense to me why this subset code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming I understand the question correctly, `dplyr` should be able to do this easily and efficiently.

```
fileName <- c("sbc016", "sbc016", "sbc016", "sbc016")
start <- c(1.345, 2.345, 615.162, 775.885)
end <- c(100.345, 200.345, 715.162, 875.885)
sbc016formants.df <- data.frame(fileName, start, end)

# list of what I want to get rid of
list16 <- c(615.162, 775.885)

install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
sbc016formants.df %>% filter(!start %in% list16)
```

or

```
sbc016formants.df %>% filter(start != list16)
```

Comment: This does work, although I'm still not sure why previous solutions failed. Thank you!